# Vue filter data to show name, not ID

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Hi I have a grid component created in Vue. The typeOfLeave shows the ID of the type of leave in the grid, but I wish it to show the name of the type of leave, not the ID. How can I filter the data to show the name? The typeOfLeave gets selected in a dropdown in a modal (code for that not needed here), and when added it must display the text of the type of leave in the grid but instead it shows the ID.

The component:

```
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <grid-component style="min-width:1200px;"
            :grid-Title="leaveGridData.title"
            :grid-Data="leaveComputed"
            :columns="leaveGridData.gridColumns"
            :filter-key="leaveGridData.filter"
            :grouped-key="leaveGridData.groupBy">
        </grid-component>
    </div>
```

The Vue:

```
      var internalApps = new Vue({
    el: "#internal",
    data: function() {
        return {
          leaveData: <?php echo $internal ?>,
          leaveTypeData: [],
          leaveGridData: {
            title: 'Leave Application',
            filter: true,
            groupBy: [],
            gridColumns: [

              {name: 'typeOfLeave', displayName: 'Type Of Leave', align:'text-left', filter:true, filterType: 'string', filterValue: ''},

            ],
          },


        }
    },
    created: function() {
      getLeaveType();
    },
    updated: function() {

    },
    computed: {
      leaveComputed: function(){
            return _.chain(this.leaveData).map(function(value){
                var data = {};
                data.id = value.id;

                data.typeOfLeave = value.typeOfLeave;


                return data ;
            }).value();

        },
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to understand. Can you please edit your question and make it more clear? And try to provide some other simple code of your problem so we can understand exactly what you need

Comment: Okay I edited my question a bit - is it more understandable now?

Comment: No actually is totally unclear .. can you please provide us a simpler example of code that explains the problem you want to solve?

Comment: Okay I simplified my code